# SSIS Expression get previous day 11:59 pm

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

```
      DATEADD("Day", -1,(DT_DBDATE)DATEDIFF("Day", (DT_DBDATE) 0, GETDATE()))
```

so i am still getting used to SQL/SSIS. I wanted to get the previous days DATE TIME so it would be 5/15/2018 11:59 PM. I was able to research and find an expression that gets the previous date at 12am

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to do this within an SSIS expression, you're looking at something like

```
DATEADD("minute", -1, (DT_DATE)((DT_DBDATE) GETDATE()))
```

Reading right to left..

GETDATE() is evaluated and provides the date and time as of RIGHT NOW. Blink and it'll get updated.

(DT_DBDATE) is a cast to a data type that only supports dates, no time component.

However, we need time to get back to the data type of DT_DATE because that supports time so `(DT_DATE)((DT_DBDATE) GETDATE())` is a clever way to reset a date to midnight within SSIS.

We then use the DATEADD function to substract 1 minute from the above.

Another approach, left to the humble reader, would be to use string manipulation for the time component. Reset the day to Midnight and then concatenate the required time on to the end as a string and then cast that back to a DT_DATE.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for your needs.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work (used today's date to demonstrate):

```
select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)-(1/cast(1440 as float))
```